# Jenkins: use of jira-trigger with pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-jira-trigger

I saw the jira-trigger-plugin for jenkins and i´m thinking about how to integrate this trigger under my jenkins pipeline environment.

I have spent my last 2 days searching about this but without success. Someone know how to use this trigger with a jenkinsfile for pipelines?

Thanks!